# Angular 2 sidenav with Angular 2 material

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidebar

I wish to design a fixed toolbar with sidenav. I am not finding proper guidance, especially with Angular 2 Material. 
What I want to achieve is this   [Sidenav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW7hn.png)
Any guidance, reference or any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [template](https://plnkr.co/edit/EBSjqUIUka9koOCYoaU6?p=preview) you can get started with.

html:

```
<md-toolbar color="accent">
    <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>￼
    <h1>Angular</h1>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container style="height: 91vh;background: yellow">

  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" style="background: orange">
    Sidenav!
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
 </md-tab-group>

</md-sidenav-container>

<footer style="background: skyblue">This is footer</footer>
```

Comment: Doesn't everything need to be inside md-sidenav-container?

Comment: If you want the sidenav to overlap everything, then sure, put everything inside the `md-sidenav-container`. If you don't want the toolbar and footer to  be covered by sidenav, then take them outside  the `md-sidenav-container`.